# Apache equivalent of vsftpd's local_enable

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

vsftpd has an option `local_enable` that allows FTP users to be directly mapped to local users. It even works without any extra effort with our Likewise Active Directory configuration.

I've been looking all over, and I can't seem to find an equivalent for Apache .htaccess. The auth providers seem to be file, DBM, LDAP and DBD. None of these seem to allow for HTTP auth user mapping to local user accounts.

Is there any way to do this? If not, why not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at mod_auth_pam: http://pam.sourceforge.net/mod_auth_pam/ (Most distros should have a package for this if it's not included as standard with apache)

You still use apache basic auth, but the module allows you to use the local user accounts for authentication, as well as a bunch of other password databases. I'll repeat the warning on the above site: **it should be used in conjunction with SSL/TLS.**

Comment: This looks very promising! I'll try it out and tell you how it goes.